# How can I modify the backfacing of a mesh's material with another mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, modifiers, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I'm trying to find some way to clean up the backfacing around child meshes on this model.

[image: main model with four children]

It uses a solidify modifier and a backfacing material to generate an outline, which I'd like to modify around the children and update procedurally (as each of the children will be rigged at some point to move around while shrinkwrapped or IK clamped to the body).

Each of the children uses the exact same modifier and materials setup as the parent.

My first thought was to use a vertex group to control the solidify modifier, but how can I ensure that group updates based on the position of the children? Weight painting can control the inclusion of vertices into a group with geometry nodes, but then how can I update the weight painting based on the children?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Backfacing material for an outline is a pretty neat idea, but it has the problem you’ve encountered. However, freestyle seems like it would work fine here. Why not use it?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I don't like how little control I have over freestyle (and it is very easy to tell when freestyle goes bad). I'd rather create outlines via nodes because I can tweak every little detail with vertex groups and weights, it's just a matter of learning how to do that.

Comment: Do you know about the line sets and other controls in the render layers section?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Yes, but again, it's more restrictive. I can't use geometry nodes as part of the freestyle modifier stack, which wouldn't likely introduce any complications with multiple meshes on one geometry node setup because each object has to be on a different layer so you can give them different line sets to tweak them individually and composit them anyway. Basically, I'd use it if the complications surrounding freestyle per-scene-object were resolved, but they aren't. Any suggestions for updating a vertex group's members based on vertex weights?